# не работает команда pip install в терминале python

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, pip

на любые взаимодействия с pip install в терминале получаю данный вывод

```
(venv) C:\Users\damer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', Connection
ResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf86859
4b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', Connection
ResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf86859
4b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', Connection
ResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf86859
4b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', Connection
ResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf86859
4b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', Connection
ResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf86859
4b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/
46/f9/d78955c88e045fa220392cc311e41764f8decf868594b5f92d8fa1d1b39e/pandas-1.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRes
etError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)))

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\damer\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

перепробовал все варианты что нагуглил , ничего не помогает.
Мне главное чтобы модули работали в проекте , а не работа pip , то есть если модуль можно как то скачать и перенести , то это тоже будет решением
(сразу скажу что easy_install и другие сторонние установщики пробовал , не подходит )

Comment: Что-то не дает доступ к тому сайту. Доступно https://files.pythonhosted.org/ ?

Comment: @gil9red нет , не доступно

Comment: Странно это. Так не должно быть. Если разберетесь с причиной недоступности сайта, то сможете устанавливать. Возможно у вас какая-то прокси используется или провайдер блокирует?

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно обновить `pip` этой командой:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Данное указание находится в самой последней строке вашей ошибки:

```
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\damer\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Не бойтесь в следующий раз переводить ошибки через переводчик Нередко спасает от глупых ошибок

Comment: pip чуть ли не каждую неделю хочет обновляться. Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, на установку пакетов никак не влияет.

Comment: @insolor, ну не знай... Я месяца 2 не прогал, а тут решил в `Kivy` покопаться, и мне `pip` не давал ничего установить, пока я не обновлюсь

Comment: См. комментарии к вопросу. Если files.pythonhosted.org даже в браузере не открывается, то обновление pip ни на что не повлияет. Это явно какая-то проблема с провайдером.

Comment: Ещё как вариант - почистить DNS: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: @insolor, а, всё, понял. Не заметил сначал

Comment: @DGDays да вы правы на пк мне помогло почистить dns , но на ноутбуке нет , та же самая ошибка

Comment: Странно... Значит надо искать дальше-_-

Comment: Возможно, у вас какой-то брандмауэр блокает на ноуте

Comment: Вы какую ОС используете?